# C: Reading file from txt file and inserting into arrays. comma as a separator

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

So I have a .txt file that has records looking like this:

```
1234567, John, Doe
```

and I have arrays in my C code where I want to read these values and insert them into:

```
int id[36] = {0};
char first_name[36];
char last_name[36];
```

So they idea is that,for example, 1234567 is at index 0 of id, John is at index 0 of first_name, and doe is at index 0 of last_name. And I want to do this with 36 similar lines.

I've investigated FILE IO but I haven't found anything pertaining to this. What's the best way of doing it? Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Have you learned about `struct` types yet?  I'm guessing not, in which case you are excused for not using them.  If you have learned about them, then this is a classic example of where you should use them.  You'd have an array of a structure type, where each structure contains the ID, first and last names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a loop that reads the content of your file using `fscanf`. Check the return value to be `3` indicating that all three items were read:

```
// id is OK as os
int id[36] = {0};
// make first_name and last_name arrays of arrays
char first_name[36][36];
char last_name[36][36];
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(fd, "%d, %35[^,], %35s", &id[i], first_name[i], last_name[i]) == 3) {
    i++;
    if (i == 36) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The format string of `fscanf` specifies the first argument is an `int` followed by a comma and whitespace, then a sequence of 35 non-commas, a comma again, and up to 35 characters for the last name.

Comment: When I write %35[^,] it's giving me a complaint (in sublime text it's highlighting it). Any reason why?

Comment: @GiancarloManuelGuerraSalvá There is no reason to highlight it for a compliant compiler, because it's perfectly valid C99. [See it compile and run with the strictest compatibility checking turned on](http://ideone.com/6Rx0SV).

Comment: Yup! Tried it and realized that. And just one final note: I realized it started reading the file from the last record(record 36) all the way to the top. Also, it's not moving to a new line. How would I incorporate the \n in this to make it move to a new line?

Comment: @GiancarloManuelGuerraSalvá This should be reading file from top to bottom, and work with the newlines too. I updated the demo at the link above to read more lines. You can print it backwards if you want, though - just start at `i-1`, and decrement the index as you print the data.

Comment: I just restarted my machine and it's doing it okay now. Thanks for all the help! though what a weird thing to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fscanf` to read the file in one line at a time and parse it with `strtok` which allows you to specify a particular field delimeter